# Setting User-Agent correctly for a command line app?

Tags: node.js, http, user-agent, github-api

I built a nodejs [command line utility](https://github.com/AWinterman/gist-put) to make posting gists from the command line both easy and secure. It works well enough, but I was wondering what the right way to set the User-Agent for such a thing is.

Right now it is set to a basically arbitrary string: "nodejs/0.0.1 (node) gist command line tool v0.0.1".

Are there guidelines on setting a user agent? Is there any reason to set it correctly? Are there any negative consequences to setting it incorrectly? All I'm doing is making a few http requests.

Comment: See my comment on @Outsider's answer, but also, please either include a URL to your project or simply the name of your project.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think guidelines is in [RFC 2068](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2068.txt) (14.42) (and [RFC 1945](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1945.txt) is almost same)

As RFC 2068, user-agent **SHOULD** like this

```
User-Agent     = "User-Agent" ":" 1*( product | comment )
```

and

```
product         = token ["/" product-version]
token          = 1*<any CHAR except CTLs or tspecials>
product-version = token
comment        = "(" *( ctext | comment ) ")"
ctext          = <any TEXT excluding "(" and ")">
```

in my opinion, if you set user-agents correctly, existing web server or web application could parse your user-agent correctrly for logging, etc.

Comment: This is exactly correct. GitHub recently started requiring a User-Agent for the API so they can contact people who are seemingly abusing or misusing the API chronically. They also began parsing them for logging a few months ago (as best as I can tell).